# How to create global events in wicket?

Tags: java, wicket

The case is simple: I have several ajax components and I want to update them when some ajax action is
happened. It is easy when all of these components are in the same place and they can be reached one by another.

But if the page has a huge hierarchy this can be not so trivial and to solve this problem I would like to send some global event (which will contain an IPartialPageRequestHandler) and all these components should catch it and update himself.

How can I do this in wicket?

Actualy I see `onEvent` method in the component class and I can access IPartialPageRequestHandler inside of it:

```
public void onEvent(IEvent<?> event){
    Object payload = event.getPayload();
    if (payload instanceof IPartialPageRequestHandler) {
    ...
    }
}
```

but how can I create the global event that should be catched by this method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a custom event, for example:

```
public class CounterUpdate
{
    private final AjaxRequestTarget target;

    /**
     * Constructor
     * 
     * @param target
     */
    public CounterUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target)
    {
        this.target = target;
    }

    /** @return ajax request target */
    public AjaxRequestTarget getTarget()
    {
        return target;
    }
}
```

In your Ajax callback method broadcast it:

```
send(getPage(), Broadcast.BREADTH, new CounterUpdate(target));
```

In any Component/Behavior that is interested for this event do:

```
    @Override
    public void onEvent(IEvent<?> event)
    {
        super.onEvent(event);

        // check if this is a counter update event and if so repaint self
        if (event.getPayload() instanceof CounterUpdate)
        {
            CounterUpdate update = (CounterUpdate)event.getPayload();
            update.getTarget().add(this);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you could notify the entire page or application 'page.send(...)' or 'application.send(...)'. Wicket already does it for every AJAX event to notify the entire page hierarchy. See the end of this paragraph from user guide:

https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/guide/8.x/single.html#_how_to_use_ajax_components_and_behaviors